QGIS only show hillshade for NOAA bathymetry, not land terrain
In QGIS, I have NOAA hillshade for the South African coastline. I want to keep only the hillshade for the ocean. However the NOAA hillshade also includes the land terrain, which is low resolution and I don't want.
How can I get QGIS to only show the hillshade for oceans, not the land terrain?

You have to clip your hillshade data (raster?) with ocean(s). Coastlines can be found here: https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/coastlines.html, clipping/masking here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/training_manual/processing/cutting_merging.html

Yes hillshade is raster. Finding a coastline is not a problem, but using that to create a polygon is a problem.  The mentioned tutorial does not show how to do that - rather it creates a bounding box from scratch.  So the deeper problem is how to how to create a closed polygon from an open polyline coastline.

There is another dataset linked on OSM site: https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html - try this one, otherwise create a bounding box polygon covering your area of interest, get Africa polygon (and other lands required) and find an intersection between them. It will be your mask.

Yes I tried the water polygons from OSM, but that failed with errors.
